# Node.JS and raw-socket doesn't seem to respect source IP

Tags: node.js, ip, wireshark, raw-sockets, tshark

I'm testing `Node.JS` and `raw-socket` for sending out custom `packets`.
It seems to work fine, however, it doesn't respect `source` `IP`.

This is my example:

```
var buffer = Buffer.alloc(65535);
var buffer = Buffer.from([
0x06, 0x27, 0xE2, 0xF1, 0xDD, 0x1D, 0x06, 0xCC, 0x72, 0x84, 0xD7, 0x79, 0x08, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00,
0x00, 0x54, 0xA3, 0x8A, 0x40, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x01, 0x24, 0xAE, 0x64, 0x60, 0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x08,
0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0x15, 0xAF, 0x07, 0x46, 0x00, 0x01, 0x39, 0x28, 0x0A, 0x5C, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0xD5, 0xB2, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15,
0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25,
0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2F, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35,
0x36, 0x37
]);

var raw = require ("raw-socket");
var socket = raw.createSocket ({protocol: raw.Protocol.ICMP});
const decoders = require('cap').decoders;

var ret = decoders.Ethernet(buffer);
ret = decoders.IPV4(buffer, ret.offset);
offset = decoders.Ethernet(buffer).offset;
dst = ret.info.dstaddr;

var buffer = buffer.slice(ret.offset, nbytes);

var nbytes = 98;

socket.send (buffer, 0, buffer.length, dst, function (error, bytes) {
    if (error) console.log (error.toString ());
});
```

The `buffer` contains an `ICMP` `packet` with `source` `IP` `100.96.0.1`, but `tshark`/`wireshark` shows the following:

```
393  16.488135 76.89.22.101 -> 8.8.8.8      ICMP 100 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0746, seq=1/256, ttl=64
394  16.496964      8.8.8.8 -> 76.89.22.101 ICMP 100 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0746, seq=1/256, ttl=120 (request in 393)
```

Comment: Not sure if `raw-socket` needs modification to support change of `source` `IP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to set the **`IP_HDRINCL` flag to prevent the kernel from rewriting the IP header**. That also means you need to include the IP header in your packet, thus use `offset` instead of `ret.offset` in your call to `buffer.slice()`.

Here's the update code:

```
var buffer = Buffer.alloc(65535);
var buffer = Buffer.from([
0x06, 0x27, 0xE2, 0xF1, 0xDD, 0x1D, 0x06, 0xCC, 0x72, 0x84, 0xD7, 0x79, 0x08, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00,
0x00, 0x54, 0xA3, 0x8A, 0x40, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x01, 0x24, 0xAE, 0x64, 0x60, 0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x08,
0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0x15, 0xAF, 0x07, 0x46, 0x00, 0x01, 0x39, 0x28, 0x0A, 0x5C, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0xD5, 0xB2, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15,
0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25,
0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2F, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35,
0x36, 0x37
]);

var raw = require ("raw-socket");
var socket = raw.createSocket ({protocol: raw.Protocol.ICMP});
const decoders = require('cap').decoders;

var ret = decoders.Ethernet(buffer);
ret = decoders.IPV4(buffer, ret.offset);
offset = decoders.Ethernet(buffer).offset;
dst = ret.info.dstaddr;

var buffer = buffer.slice(offset, nbytes);

var nbytes = 98;

socket.setOption(raw.SocketLevel.IPPROTO_IP, raw.SocketOption.IP_HDRINCL, new Buffer ([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01]), 4)
socket.send (buffer, 0, buffer.length, dst, function (error, bytes) {
    if (error) console.log (error.toString ());
});
```